# Storing form schemas and functions in a Database

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My colleagues and I are building a web app with a relatively complex back end. Without giving away the product idea, we have several hundred form schemas paired with their return functions which are called when the form is submitted. The schemas are JSON objects which dynamically create a form on the client side. When the data in the form is submitted the linked functions may do a variety of different things with that data.

Currently these form schemas and linked functions are hosted in a private repo on GitHub. Is this the best way to go or could they be persisted in a database such as mongodb?

I understand mongodb will have no trouble storing the form schemas but what about the functions and the functions dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Store it into the database (as a string) and give it to the client when he requests it (will turn into a function). If you want to use that code on the backend (node), you'd eval it or make a function new Function(functionString) and do your validating on the server side as well.
/edit
Or put each schema in a file and request it server/client side when you need it. Making a DB round for something like this is expensive.