# schema of web apps for premium users

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a very big problem.

I have a web application where I have done in nodejs common users when added to the database, they can log in and change your personal details, such as title, description, order, password, but I want to add premium users, and that premium users with special functions can change things in the database that do not. such as your ID, your email address, delete your conversations, etc..

The problem is that the functions are created based on premium user requirements. That is, I need a way to create functions only for a specific user.

For example ... ANDRES user is a premium user. ANDRES only need to create and delete comments. Furthermore, a user is raw JOSE, JOSE need to create folders inside your blog.

I want to know how to make functions for jose, that only jose can use.

EDIT 1

this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781619/storing-form-schemas-and-functions-in-a-database) may be is the solution, but anybody can explain me how can i use with an example??

Comment: im searching something like schema of mongoose, but to fire events or functions from different users

Comment: typically you would just expose the premium UI to the premium user. And be sure your api is checking permissions to perform actions.